# System.OutOfMemoryException in C# when Generating huge amount of byte[] objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, out-of-memory

I'm using this code to modify a pdf tmeplate to add specific details to it,

```
private static byte[] GeneratePdfFromPdfFile(byte[] file, string landingPage, string code)
        {

            try
            {

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new PdfReader(file))
                    {
                        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
                        {
                            string _embeddedURL = "http://" + landingPage + "/Default.aspx?code=" + code + "&m=" + eventCode18;
                            PdfAction act = new PdfAction(_embeddedURL);
                            stamper.Writer.SetOpenAction(act);
                            stamper.Close();
                            reader.Close();
                            return ms.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"AttachmentException.txt", ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

this Method is being called from this Method:

```
 public static byte[] GenerateAttachment(AttachmentExtenstion type, string Contents, string FileName, string code, string landingPage, bool zipped, byte[] File = null)
        {
            byte[] finalVal = null;
            try
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case AttachmentExtenstion.PDF:
                        finalVal = GeneratePdfFromPdfFile(File, landingPage, code);
                        break;
                    case AttachmentExtenstion.WordX:
                    case AttachmentExtenstion.Word:
                        finalVal = GenerateWordFromDocFile(File, code, landingPage);
                        break;
                    case AttachmentExtenstion.HTML:
                        finalVal = GenerateHtmlFile(Contents, code, landingPage);
                        break;
                }
                return zipped ? _getZippedFile(finalVal, FileName) : finalVal;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

and here is the main caller,

```
 foreach (var item in Recipients)
                {
//...
//....
 item.EmailAttachment = AttachmentGeneratorEngine.GenerateAttachment(_type, "", item.AttachmentName, item.CMPRCode, _cmpTmp.LandingDomain, _cmpTmp.AttachmentZip.Value, _cmpTmp.getFirstAttachment(item.Language, item.DefaultLanguage));
}
```

The **AttachmentGeneratorEngine.GenerateAttachment** method is being called approx. 4k times, because I'm adding a specific PDF file from a PDF template for every element in my List.

recently I started having this exception:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.   at System.IO.MemoryStream.ToArray()
```

I already implemented IDisposible in the classes and and I made sure that all of them are being released.

Note: it was running before very smoothely and also I double checked the system's resources - 9 GB is used out of 16 GB, so I had enough memory available.

==========================================

Update:
Here is the code that loops through the list

```
  public static bool ProcessGroupLaunch(string groupCode, int customerId, string UilangCode)
        {
            CampaignGroup cmpGList = GetCampaignGroup(groupCode, customerId, UilangCode)[0];
            _campaigns = GetCampaigns(groupCode, customerId);
            List<CampaignRecipientLib> Recipients = GetGroupRcipientsToLaunch(cmpGList.ID, customerId);
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in _campaigns)
                    item.Details = GetCampaignDetails(item.CampaignId.Value, UilangCode);

                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

                #region single-threaded ForEach

                foreach (var item in Recipients)
                {
                    CampaignLib _cmpTmp = _campaigns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CampaignId.Value == item.CampaignId);
                    bool IncludeAttachment = _cmpTmp.IncludeAttachment ?? false;
                    bool IncludeAttachmentDoubleBarrel = _cmpTmp.IncludeAttachmentDoubleBarrel ?? false;

                    if (IncludeAttachment)
                    {
                        if (_cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower().Equals("doc") || (_cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower().Equals("docx")))
                            _type = AttachmentGeneratorEngine.AttachmentExtenstion.Word;
                        else if (_cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower().Equals("ppt") || (_cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower().Equals("pptx")))
                            _type = AttachmentGeneratorEngine.AttachmentExtenstion.PowePoint;
                        else if (_cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower().Equals("xls") || (_cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower().Equals("xlsx")))
                            _type = AttachmentGeneratorEngine.AttachmentExtenstion.Excel;
                        else if (_cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower().Equals("pdf"))
                            _type = AttachmentGeneratorEngine.AttachmentExtenstion.PDF;
                        else if (_cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower().Equals("html"))
                            _type = AttachmentGeneratorEngine.AttachmentExtenstion.HTML;
                    }


                        //set "recpient" details
                        item.EmailFrom = _cmpTmp.EmailFromPrefix + "@" + _cmpTmp.EmailFromDomain;
                        item.EmailBody = GetChangedPlaceHolders((_cmpTmp.getBodybyLangCode(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Language) ? item.DefaultLanguage : item.Language, item.DefaultLanguage)), item.ID, _cmpTmp.CustomerId.Value, _cmpTmp.CampaignId.Value);

                        if (item.EmailBody.Contains("[T-LandingPageLink]"))
                        {
                           //..
                        }

                        if (item.EmailBody.Contains("[T-FeedbackLink]"))
                        {
                           //..
                        }

                        if (item.EmailBody.Contains("src=\".."))
                        {
                            //..
                        }


                        //set flags to be used by the SMTP Queue and Scheduler
                        item.ReadyTobeSent = true;
                        item.PickupReady = false;


                        //add attachment to the recipient, if any.
                        if (IncludeAttachment)
                        {
                            item.AttachmentName = _cmpTmp.getAttachmentSubjectbyLangCode(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Language) ? item.DefaultLanguage : item.Language, item.DefaultLanguage) + "." + _cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower();


                            try
                            {
                                if (_type == AttachmentGeneratorEngine.AttachmentExtenstion.PDF || _type == AttachmentGeneratorEngine.AttachmentExtenstion.WordX || _type == AttachmentGeneratorEngine.AttachmentExtenstion.Word)
                                    item.EmailAttachment = AttachmentGeneratorEngine.GenerateAttachment(_type, "", item.AttachmentName, item.CMPRCode, _cmpTmp.LandingDomain, _cmpTmp.AttachmentZip.Value, _cmpTmp.getFirstAttachment(item.Language, item.DefaultLanguage));
                                else item.EmailAttachment = AttachmentGeneratorEngine.GenerateAttachment(_type, value, item.AttachmentName, item.CMPRCode, _cmpTmp.LandingDomain, _cmpTmp.AttachmentZip.Value);

                                item.AttachmentName = _cmpTmp.AttachmentZip.Value ? (_cmpTmp.getAttachmentSubjectbyLangCode(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Language) ? item.DefaultLanguage : item.Language, item.DefaultLanguage) + ".zip") :
                                                 _cmpTmp.getAttachmentSubjectbyLangCode(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Language) ? item.DefaultLanguage : item.Language, item.DefaultLanguage) + "." + _cmpTmp.AttachmentExtension.ToLower();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            item.EmailAttachment = null;
                            item.AttachmentName = null;
                        }


                }
                #endregion

                stopWatch.Stop();
                bool res = WriteCampaignRecipientsLaunch(ref Recipients);
                return res;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Recipients.ForEach(i => i.Dispose());
                cmpGList.Dispose();

                Recipients = null;
                cmpGList = null;

                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                Recipients.ForEach(i => i.Dispose());
                cmpGList.Dispose();

                Recipients = null;                
                cmpGList = null;

            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with disposing resources, that all looks ok.  The problem might lie in the loop which is storing the result of that method for 4000 instances of `Recipients`.

Comment: Are you compiling to 32 to 64 bit?  That can effect the max size of objects.

Comment: @juharr i'm using x64

Comment: @PhilCooper I added the code that loops through the List<Recipients> to the question